# The question body does not meet our quality standards

Tags: discussion, quality-filter

I've got the following error in Stack Overflow. 
Saying that my body wasn't ok. The only thing I changed was the Title by going from **g**enerated ... **v**isual **s**tudio to **G**enerated **V**isual **S**tudio

So the body was actually fine but the title wasn't (bug?)

However if SO is going to be that strict with the validation, there must be more user friendly error messages like "you should start your title with a capitalized letter..."

[image: screen shot]

Comment: hmm maybe it didn't like the * in the title?

Comment: @Tim the * is still there but he didn't like the g (expected G) See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32116305/generated-js-from-ts-in-visual-studio-2015

Comment: I know, but I'm just thinking it could have also been fixed if you removed the stars (e.g. having a * gives a bad rating of 2, and no capitals a rating of 1, and if the rating is 3 or more it blocks.

Comment: wonder if this strange block was triggered if you capitalized two occurrences where you wrote i instead of I in the last note ("If i want to... i have to...")

Comment: @gnat is correct, plus also try wrapping the `*.js` and `*.ts` with backticks as the system might detect this as code. (and since there are no code blocks at all in the post, thinks you posted unformatted code)